# serialize all forms in jquery, to send data to Controller in a List of presenter

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, controller

I have n forms with the id "form-value-@model.id" generated in loop in a cshtml partial like this

```
    <div class="container-principal">
    @for(val c in @Model.what)
    {
       @Html.Partial("Form/_Forms", Model.formPresenter);
    }
    <button class="icon">Go</button>
    </div>
    
//Partial
        <div id="@model.id">
          <form id="form-value-@model.id" method="post">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="container">
                <label> Model
                  <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Desc)
                  </span>
                </label>
              </div>
              @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.go)
              @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id)
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

This is method in javascript called by .icon button

```
function go() {
    
    var myForms = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="form-value-"]');

    var formSelector = ["#sdd-data", "#form-payment-methods", myForms];
    var data = $("#sdd-data").serialize() + "&" + $("#form-payment-methods").serialize() + "&" + $(myForms).serialize();

    validatedMultiFormElab({
        formSelector: formSelector,
        data: data,
        url: creaUrl("Go", "Check"),
        onSuccessFunction: function (response) {
            //some code
        },
        onErrorFunction: function (data) {
            hideModal('#waitmodal');
        }
    });
}


function validatedMultiFormElab(parameters) {
    var input = {
        url: parameters.url,
        method: "POST",
        data: parameters.data,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.technicalError) {
                technicalError(result);
            }
            else if (result.success) {
                if (typeof onPreSuccessFunction != "undefined" && !parameters.skipPreSuccessFunction) {
                    onPreSuccessFunction(result);
                }

                jQuery.each(parameters.formSelector, function (index, singleFormSelector) {
                    if (singleFormSelector) {
                        cleanErrors(singleFormSelector);
                    }
                });

                if (parameters.onSuccessFunction != undefined) {
                    parameters.onSuccessFunction(result.outcome);
                }
            }
            else {
                mapValidationMultiFormResults(result);

                if (parameters.onErrorFunction != undefined) {
                    parameters.onErrorFunction(result.outcome);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            if (xhr.responseJSON && xhr.responseJSON.technicalError)
                technicalError(xhr.responseJSON);
            else
                technicalError();
        },
    };

    if (parameters.usaFormData) {
        input.contentType = false;
        input.processData = false;
    }
    return $.ajax(input);
}
```

Finally the action in Controller class

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Go(PaymentOwnerDataVM model, List<PaymentMethodVM> payments, List<FormDataVM> formPresenter)
{
    //some code
}
```

model is always ok(is a single form),payments is a form with multi input generated in a loop and maybe null but no problem,formPresenter(the presented where to serialize the inputs of my forms) is always null, where am I wrong?